# Building PhantomJS 2.0 on Windows results in a strange error

Tags: qt, webkit, phantomjs, qtwebkit, qwebkit

I am trying to build PhantomJS 2.0 on Windows from the **c:\fastio\phantomjs\phantomjs** directory. For some reason, the build process fails after a while, with 2 errors (see error message below):

1) It tries to access **"C:fastiophantomjsphantomjssrcqtqtbasebinmoc.exe"**. Obviously, the backslash characters between directory names are somehow getting stripped away deep in the build process - possibly a mismatch between Windows-style **"\"** and Linux-style **"/"** (but this is only a guess).

2) There's another error, "Failed to read names from file: C:/fastio/phantomjs/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore/mathml/mathtags.in".

**If I remove sh.exe from the PATH, the build still gets to this point, and only error #2 appears, leading me to think that error #2 is the real problem here.**

Here is the full error message (as far as I can tell this is happening while building WebKit):

```
sh: C:fastiophantomjsphantomjssrcqtqtbasebinmoc.exe: command not found
Failed to read names from file: C:/fastio/phantomjs/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore/mathml/mathtags.in at C:/fastio/phantomjs/phantomjs/src/qt/qtwebkit/Source/WebCore/dom/make_names.pl line 315.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\Eugene\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_c2ba306e536fdf878271f7fe636a147ff37326ad\bin\perl.EXE' : return code '0x7f'
Stop.
```

(By the way, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769056/building-phantomjs-2-from-source-on-windows) but I'm already past the issues described there, my error is happening later in the build process.)

How can I make this work?

**Full logs below:**

Console output:
http://pastebin.com/btMeNPz4

QT build log file build_qt_4-285-20-0859.log:
http://pastebin.com/LUEJz7E0

WebKit build log file build_webkit_4-285-20_0859.log:
http://pastebin.com/494TivXF

PhantomJS build log file build_phantomjs_4-285-20_0859.log:
**Empty**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I found the solution myself, here were my steps:

1. Remove as much as possible from the PATH leaving only the entries critical to the build process
2. Most importantly, **remove all GitHub's git directories from the PATH**
3. Install GIT separately (**not** from GitHub but from git-scm.com), add its **cmd** directory only (not its **bin** directory) to the PATH
4. Install ActivePerl separately, add it to the PATH

It's moving past the error I asked about with the steps above (still not sure if it will finish the build successfully, it's taking a while).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had the same problem and following your advice worked

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once. Thanks, this: "remove all GitHub's git directories from the PATH" helped to finally build.  You should accept this as an answer, it's worth it.